# "using namespace ...." Why?

Tags: visual-c++, namespaces, turbo-c++

I am new to C++ programming and we make use of Turbo C++ (old IDE) to compile our programs. The problem is that in Turbo C++ we never make use of namespaces or even std::cout while programming. We just type cout<<.... to output things.

Recently, I began using Visual C++ 2010 to write my programs and we supposedly have to use 'using namespace std' or 'std::' here. But, I got the output even when I used just cout<<..... and no 'using namespace std' (compiler showed error but got output).

Therefore, I am failing to understand the use of namespaces. Could someone help me out ?

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces simply allow a programmer to avoid construct naming collisions. That way I can use multiple libraries without the individual libraries having to worry about their classes having the same name. Java does something similar with packages, and C# does something similar that they call namespaces too.

The `using namespace` syntax simply means that the compiler should search that namespace for anything that it can't find declared in the current scope.

If you're not being forced to use the fully qualified `std::` name or the `using namespace` syntax, then something in your program is likely already including it, probably in an `#include`ed file.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have always been using a (precompiled) (header) include that contained 'using namespace std'; It is the ANSI C++ standard that mandates that the standard library is (and always has been) in namespace std

Comment: No, the compiler is just that old (ca. 1993 for Turbo C++ 3.0), so it's pre-standard.  Everything's in the global namespace.  It's a relic.

Comment: What.. they had STL back then? Why didn't they tell me earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are useful in determining which class to use. Say your program has a class called "Sample". You also have one or more DLLs that have defined a class called "Sample".

When you create a new instance of "Sample", how does it know which implementation to use? You use namespacing to differentiate the type that is to be created.